# Дополнительная кодировка кириллицы в RTK query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

Я использую RTK query и react с typescript. При разработке приложения кириллица в ссылке работала нормально. Например, "/main/привет" был закодирован 1 раз на локальном бэкенде. Но теперь у нас бэкенд на сервере reg ru и запросы дополнительно закодированы.

[image: в дебагере]

То есть, вместо "%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82"(привет) отправляет в бэкенд дополнительно закодированный "%25D0%259F%25D1%2580%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B5%25D1%2582"(привет закодированный 2 раза). Я посмотрел в отладчик и в request все в порядке, но в response уже другой URL . Как я понял, запрос дополнительно закодирован под капотом RTK query. Как эту ошибку можно исправить?

Я хочу, чтобы кириллица не кодировалась 2 раза

Comment: [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) скорее всего то, что вам нужно

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).